# Creating a private and protected members in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, private-members

Can you share your views on Creating a private and protected members in Javascript.

I mean really protective not just convention like Douglas Crockford said.

**Do not use _ (underbar) as the first character of a name. It is sometimes used to indicate privacy, but it does not actually provide privacy. If privacy is important, use the forms that provide private members. Avoid conventions that demonstrate a lack of competence.**

```
       "use strict";

        function MyMain(){
          this.checkauth=false;
        }

        MyMain.prototype.init=function(){
          return Object.create(this);
        }

        MyMain.prototype.authenticate=function(key){

 //resp is server response hold true for the given key.  here validate method will interact with server and get concerned response
             var resp=validate(key);
            if(resp){
              this.checkauth=true;
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        MyMain.prototype.test=function(){
          if(this.checkauth==true){
            console.log("this is working")
          }else{
              console.log("Not authorized")
          } 
        }
```

Well i failed in explaining see the Edit i have made.

i have no intention of making authorization on client side. I made it on server and making private member true saying server has validated the user and my question is how to make this secure.

and users who have access to my Javascript file can read all of it and authenticate like this.

```
var main=new MyMain();
main.checkauth=true;
main.test();
```

Looking for help on creating secure authentication via javascript.

Comment: Never trust client-side code. _Always_ validate user input server-side.

Comment: "Looking for help on creating secure authentication via javascript." I imagine the best help you're going to get is: Don't.

Comment: Do you think "protected members" cannot be inspected or accessed at all? I'm afraid I have to disabuse you of that notion. "Conventional" privacy is no more secure in terms of actual security than anything else. It's still all just Javascript running in your browser. Member encapsulation and access protection is just to help developers communicate intended usage, nothing more, nothing less. As far as that goes, an underscore is worth the same as a scoped variable.

Answer (score 6):

While there are various ways to mask variables and make then tricky to access, the main benefits of these techniques is that they stop you from accessing them *by accident*.

The owner of the browser has access to *all of the code* and *all of the data* that you send to the browser.

You can't stop them accessing it.

If you want to do secure authentication then you *must* do it on the server.

> i have no intention of making authorization on client side.

If you weren't doing authz client side, then users setting `main.checkauth=true;` wouldn't be a problem for you.

You need to *not send* the data and JavaScript that should be available only to authorized users if the user isn't authorized. At the moment you seem to be authorizing on the server but sending all the data/JS that is for authorized users to the client regardless (just with a little bit of client side code that says "Please don't look at this").

Comment: And maybe he's running JavaScript snippets on his ASP.net server somehow. If the OP were using node.js, he would've tagged it, and he wouldn't worry about users accessing the JS file.

Comment: I have no idea of doing auth in client side, i have used Facebook SDK, I am keeping that in mind. I need to make private variable true on server response

Comment: @saikiran — That doesn't solve your problem. A private variable is still running under the control of the user. You need to authenticate via your server and not just trust the browser when it tells you the user has authenticated with Facebook.

Comment: Basically: Browser says: _"Dude, I'm authorized"_ > Server says: _"No you're not!"_ > server refuses to send HTML / JS for pages that require authorization.

Comment: well my doubt is exactly the same, how to maintain the authentication from server through out all methods that i have in my class

Comment: You don't. You just don't send the JavaScript (or data) which should be available only to authorised users to the browser at all unless they have authenticated and you have confirmed that authentication on your server.